# Beginners issue with scope in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I am working with angular at frontend and django as backend, writing smll stuff to learn angular.I am trying to display variable i defined in scope.I am loading the html as partial onclick of anchor tag.
Here is my app.js which have my router settings:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp',['ngRoute'])

blogApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});

blogApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'static/partials/login.html',
      }).
      when('/register',{
        templateUrl:'static/partials/register.html',
      }).
      when('/shoppingcart', {
        templateUrl:'static/partials/shopping_cart.html',
        controller:'CartController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
}]);
```

Here is my CartController defined:

```
blogApp.controller('CartController', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
                    {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
                ];

});
```

i have included the js which contains my CartController and the one that has defined my routing.My partial (called shopping_cart.html) is like this:

```
<div ng-controller='CartController'>
    <h3>Your Cart</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <span>{% item.title %}</span>
        <input ng-model="item.quantity">
        <span> {% item.price|currency %} </span>
        <span> {% item.price * item.quantity | currency %} </span>
        <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Intriguing problem is that item.quantity is displayed correctly but item.title, item.price etc is displayed as it is in my output.Point is if it displays item.quantity this implies that item variable is containing the variable defined, even if i put item.title in input in place of item.quantity it displays the variable, But {% item.title %} on its own never gets displayed.Plese point me to my mistake, and kindly explain why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typo.

In your config you override the start and end symbol for interpolation to '{$' and '$}', but in your template you use '{%' and '%}' instead. Replace the % with $ and it should work.

Comment: yes thanks i had this habit of writing like this before as it is valid in django.Thanks for thy careful eyes.:)